# How do I make my links be next to each other in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an assignment for a coding class and I have been trying quite hard to get my links in my code to be next to each other in my navigation bar, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to have them next to each other. They're just blue, underlined links on top of each other. My HTML and CSS codes are below. If someone would please help me I would really appreciate it.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang=""> 


    <head>


       <style>

body{ background-image: url("js/images/htmlbackground.jpeg");      
}
 </style>




        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Courtney Geller</title>
        <meta name="The works of Courtney Geller" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">



        <!--the information cascades down to the classes below! -->
        <!-- you have to put all your styles and things into this so that the file can find it in this folder! This is where it looks for everything!-->

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.js"></script>



           </head>



    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->   

<div class= "maincontainer">
    <div class="navBar">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
       <div><ul><li><a href=" ftp://locomoku.com/courtney-geller/Project%201-Home/index.html">About Me</a></li></ul>
  <li><a href="courtneygellerphotography.tumblr.com">My Work</a></li>
        </ul></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class= "mainpicture">     
     <img src="js/images/frontimage.png" alt= "Front image" height="200" width= "350">     
 </div>    

    <div>
        <p class="more"; text-align: center;>I'm Courtney, I'm from Maine and I'm a certified weather spotter. My major is Art, Technology and Culture at the University of Oklahoma, and my minor is Meteorology.<br>I like baking, knitting, weather, and mozzarella sticks.<br>For more about me and some of my work, click the links above.</p>

     </div>   



     <script type="text/javascript" accesskey="" ></script>



        <image: src = "js/images/htmlbackground.jpeg">



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>








        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>



    </body>


</html>



CSS:


body {

    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
    .more { 
    margin-left: 430px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top:265px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:center;  
}


    .navBar{
     background-color: #222;
     display: inline-block;
}

    #nav_wrapper{
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; 
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;   
margin: 0;
position: relative; 
display: inline-block;
}    

#nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;  
}

#nav ul li:hover{
  background-color: #ccc;  
}

#nav ul li a, visited{
background-color: white;
    color: #ff903f;
    border: 2px solid none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left:460px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
}

#nav ul li a:hover{
  color: #ccc; 
  text-decoration: none;
}




.mainpicture{
position: absolute;
top: 135px;
left: 430px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS code:

```
 ul li{
 float:left;
 display:inline;
```

}

or:

```
ul li a{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;}/*or the width you want*/
```

and than: 
please use     #nav ul li a:link, a:visitet NOT #nav ul li a, visited.

An please remember a:hover comes allways after a:link and a:visited

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang=""> 


    <head>


       <style>

body{ background-image: url("js/images/htmlbackground.jpeg");      
}
 </style>




        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Courtney Geller</title>
        <meta name="The works of Courtney Geller" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">



        <!--the information cascades down to the classes below! -->
        <!-- you have to put all your styles and things into this so that the file can find it in this folder! This is where it looks for everything!-->

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.js"></script>



           </head>



    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->   

<div class= "maincontainer">
    <div class="navBar">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
       <div>
       <ul>
       <li><a href=" ftp://locomoku.com/courtney-geller/Project%201-Home/index.html">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="courtneygellerphotography.tumblr.com">My Work</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "mainpicture">     
     <img src="js/images/frontimage.png" alt= "Front image" height="200" width= "350">     
 </div>    

    <div>
        <p class="more"; text-align: center;>I'm Courtney, I'm from Maine and I'm a certified weather spotter. My major is Art, Technology and Culture at the University of Oklahoma, and my minor is Meteorology.<br>I like baking, knitting, weather, and mozzarella sticks.<br>For more about me and some of my work, click the links above.</p>

     </div>   



     <script type="text/javascript" accesskey="" ></script>



        <image: src = "js/images/htmlbackground.jpeg">



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>








        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>



    </body>


</html>

<style>
body {

    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
    .more { 
    margin-left: 430px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top:265px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:center;  
}


    .navBar{
     background-color: #222;
        text-align:right;
}

    #nav_wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; 
}

#nav_wrapper ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;   
margin: 0;
} 
#nav_wrapper li{
    display: initial;
    padding:10px 10px;
}
#nav_wrapper ul li:hover{
  background-color: #ccc;  
}

#nav_wrapper ul li a: visited{
background-color: white;
    color: #ff903f;
    border: 2px solid none;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav_wrapper ul li a:hover{
  color: #ccc; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
```